# How many integers up to 200 have exactly four factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there an easier way to work this out without actually counting the amount of numbers?

I have started to count and have realised that nearly only numbers which are only divisible only by 1,2, half of n, and n have for factors.

Comment: What do you mean by four factors ?

Comment: To have exactly $4$ factors you must have the form $pq$ or the form $p^3$.

Comment: I mean numbers that have exactly four factors

Comment: When someone asks you to clarify a point, simply repeating what you said is not a helpful response.  Give an example or two to show what you mean.  And, no, there is no easier way to compute a number than by computing it.

Comment: Yes, there is an easier way to work this out without actually counting the amount of numbers.

Comment: Please could you tell me what it is.

Comment: @lulu How do you know beforehand it can't be of the form $p^2q^2$? I know it can't be $p^4$, but only because I know 200^{1/4} is not an integer

Comment: @ShaVuklia  My comment had nothing to do with $200$.  If $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then $d(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$, is $\prod (a_i+1)$.  Since the OP wants $d(n)=4$ we must have $2\times 2$ or $1\times 4$.

Comment: When faced with a problem like this, just go ahead and start computing the answer, listing all the numbers you get along the way.  After all, $200$ is not such a large number that you can't do this within a few minutes. As you do so, look for *patterns* in what you are getting.  At the very least, you'll be familiarizing yourself with the arithmetic of small numbers, and it'll give you something to do while your subconscious does the heavy lifting.

Comment: do you mean prime factors? For example, $12$ has two prime factors but $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$ divide $12$

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like this that look like ordinary homework problems and which show absolutely no effort.  Please edit your post to indicate what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you for telling me @lulu

Comment: Voting to close the question.  If you can, please edit to include your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$, then the number of divisors of $n$ is exactly $(e_1+1)\cdots(e_m+1) \ge 2^m$.

Or, if you want an ad hoc solution, consider this:

> If $n$ has three prime factors, then it has more than four divisors.

Comment: Could you please make it more simple what you mean.

Comment: @L.Mykhnenko Substitue numbers to make this "simpler" so as to understand this result.

Comment: lhf _claims_ that if n has 3 prime factors, then n has more than 4 divisors.  30=2x3x5.  How may factors does 30 have?  Similarly, how many factors does $3^4 = 81$ have, or $2^4 = 16$ have?  Note that I am assuming that the terms _factor_ and _divisor_ are synonymous and that 1 is a _factor_ of any n.